# Is $\delta$ in $L^\infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I think the question title says is all. I am wondering, is the Dirac delta in the Lebesgue space $L^\infty$?

Comment: No, it is not a function, and even if it were, it would be unbounded.

Comment: To be fair-if it were, it would be bounded. And continuous. And yellow.

Comment: @UmbertoP.: I have added an answer to specify what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L^{\infty}$ is a space of **functions**. Every element in $L^\infty$ is a function, and the Dirac delta is not. So the answer is *no*.

Comment: Isn't the Dirac delta a *generalized* function? Does this not count for membership in $L^\infty$?

Comment: @Wapiti It's a *generalized* function, which means it's not a function. Because you have to *generalize* the definition in order for $\delta$ to fit into it. It's like a circle is a *generalized* $n$-gon, but it is *not* a $n$-gon.

Comment: Heh...technically it's a space of equivalence classes of functions ;)

Comment: The name "generalized function" is probably the biggest abomination in mathematical analysis. Is like saying that functions are "generalized real numbers".

Answer (score 10):

In no way you can say that $\delta \in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$. The $\delta$ is not a function, but let us sweep this "detail" under the rug. We can realize $\delta$ as a limit (in some sense that is not necessary to specify): 
$$\tag{1}
\delta(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} n \zeta(nx), $$ 
where $\zeta\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a nonnegative function that integrates to $1$: 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \zeta(x)\, dx = 1.$$ 
(This is the familiar "concentrating spike" construction). Now, the sequence of functions $(n\zeta(n\cdot))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not bounded in $L^\infty$. Therefore, in no way we can expect that its limit belongs to $L^\infty$, not even in a "weak" or "generalized" way.

**Note**. On the other hand, we remark that 
$$
\|n\zeta(n\cdot)\|_{L^1(\mathbb R)} = 1$$ 
for all $n$. This suggests that "$\delta \in L^1(\mathbb R)$" in some generalized sense. And this is true. Indeed, there is the isometric embedding
$$L^1(\mathbb R)\subset M(\mathbb R), $$ 
where $M(\mathbb R)$ denotes the space of (signed) measures with finite total mass, equipped with the [total variation norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_norm_of_complex_measures). The $\delta$ is a perfectly good element of $M(\mathbb R)$.

**Note 2**. The same argument shows that $\delta\notin L^p(\mathbb R)$, for all $p>1$, not even in a generalized way.