# Example of a measure which is not an $L^1$ function.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $f\in L^1(\Omega)$, then $f$ defines a measure on $\Omega$. I wonder, can a function $f\not\in L^1(\Omega)$ define a finite measure on $\Omega$?

I know that **Dirac delta** defines a measure which is not in $L^1$, but I am bit confused whether it is a function, because it is not defined on $\Omega$ but on $\mathcal{C}_c^\infty(\Omega)$ (the space of compactly supported smooth functions) . Thanks!!

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$ , with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2198242/8157)

Comment: I suppose you want the measure to be finite?

Comment: And what do you mean by "a function which is a measure"?

Comment: @tomasz If $f\in L^1$, then  $v_f (A)$ as in Motyla's answer defines a measure on $\Omega$.

Comment: You want a measure that is not "absolutely continuous".  Probabably any measure theory text has discussion of this.

Comment: @Arun: I know that, I'm asking what you mean by a function which is a measure, but is not in $L^1$. In what sense would the function be a measure?

Comment: If the function is non-negative, then all you really need is for it to be measurable, it's just that if it's not in $L^1$, the measure will be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are unsure on the identification between (some) functions and measures. Given a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, you can define a measure $\mu_f$ by 
$$
\mu_f(A):=\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)\, dx, \quad \forall A\ \text{Lebesgue measurable},$$ 
or, more shortly, $d\mu_f := f\, dx$. The general theorem that governs this kind of constructions is [the Radon-Nikodym theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), but you do not need its full force, only the statement. If a measure $\mu_f$ is constructed like that, you say that it is *absolutely continuous* with respect to the Lebesgue measure $dx$, and you say that $f$ is the *Radon-Nikodym derivative* of $\mu_f$ with respect to $dx$, which alludes to the formal manipulation 
$$
d\mu_f = f\, dx \quad \overset{\text{formal}}{\iff}\quad f=\frac{d\mu_f}{dx}.$$

---

Your question is now: can we do this construction with a function $f$ that does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$? The answer is **no**: the writing 
$$\tag{!!}
\int_A f\, dx $$
does not make sense for all measurable $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ unless $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^n)$.

Answer (score 2):

To every measurable function $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ we can associate an expression $$v_f (A) =\int_A f(t) l_n (dt ) $$
where $l_n $ is $n$-dimensional lebesgue measure. If $v_f (A) $ is finite for every lebesgue measurable subset of $\Omega$ then it is easy to show that $f\in L_1 (\Omega ).$

Comment: Thanks. So you mean every measure which are generated by a function is in $L^1$?

Comment: @Arun: The right way of saying that is "every measure that is **absolutely continuous** with respect to the Lebesgue measure is in $L^1$". You don't say that a measure is "generated by a function", even if it is clear what you mean.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks for correcting me. Can you give me some reference for the result you stated. It is too much of asking, but I just wonder is there any function space bigger than $L^1$?

Answer (score 0):

In the whole space, $f = 1\not\in L^1$  as measure is the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: But $f$ does not define a finite measure. Could we expect a finite measure not in $L^1$.

Comment: @Arun, then edit your question an add the condition.

Comment: @Arun, what *means* that a *measure* is in $L^1$?

Comment: I have edited the question. I mixed up everything. Sorry for that.