# Is the subset $\{ f : f \in L^2[0,1], ||f||_{\infty} \leq 1\}$ of $L^2[0, 1]$ a Hilbert manifold in the latter Lebesgue space?

Tags: convex-analysis, smooth-manifolds

I know that the set $A$ of all the functions in $L^2[0,1]$ that are bounded by $1$ in the sup norm,
$$
A = \{ f : f \in L^2[0,1], ||f||_{\infty} \leq 1\},
$$ 
has no interior points in $L^2([0,1])$.  But, it is a convex and bounded subset of $L^2([0,1])$.  Can someone recommend (if it exists) what material I might read to learn to analyze such a set for a [Hilbert manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold) structure?  Many thanks.

UPDATE #1:  In an attempt to study the tangent space of $A$, I look at curves in it, parameterized by "time".  Denoting by ${\bf 1}$ the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), one such curve is:
$$
f[t](x) = {\bf 1}_{[\, t, \; t+0.1 \, ]}(x), \quad 0 \leq t \leq 0.9.
$$
An increment (for small $h > 0$, and $t < 0.9 - h$) of this curve is
$$
f[t+h](x) - f[t](x),
$$
but if on dividing this by $h$ and letting $h \rightarrow 0+$, the resulting expression doesn't tend to any function in $A$; instead it tends to a difference of two Dirac delta functions, which is not in $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by "manifold structure"?

Comment: @gerw, I mean, whether $A$ is a manifold in $L^2[0, 1]$, just like, say, the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + y^2 = 1$ is a manifold in the Euclidean 3-D space.

Comment: What is your definition of "manifold"? Typically, a manifold is finite dimensional, but $A$ is not.

Comment: Apologies.  I mean, [Hilbert manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold).  I'll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: If you found Dirac deltas then your curve is not differentiable. A Dirac delta is not an element of $L^2$. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2198242/8157

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, yes.  I am now looking for other curves.

Comment: But are you sure that thing is a Hilbert submanifold of $L^2$? It does not seem obvious to me. Anyway, I have come across some references on Hilbert manifolds sometime (not that I read them). One is Lang, "Fundamentals of differentiable geometry", but it is probably not what you need. I found a more concrete reference in the book of Braess, "Nonlinear approximation theory".

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, thank you so much for finding the references.  To answer your question, No, I am not sure: I was trying to determine whether it is a Hilbert (or any finite-dimensional) submanifold or not.  But it seems doubtful.  At any rate, thanks again.  If I find out new stuff, I'll add in updates.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, hence the "community wiki"; rather, it is another question. Why do you want such a structure on $A$?

First, it is unlikely that such structure, if it exists, would be natural. The analogous problem on $\mathbb R^2$ is searching for a manifold structure on the unit square 
$$
\{ (x, y)\ :\ \max(|x|, |y|)\le 1\}. $$
This cannot be a submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ because of its corners (we talked about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2615957/8157), by the way). So, any manifold structure we can put on it will be just an academic exercise, unlikely to be useful.

Second, the set $A$ already possesses a great deal of useful properties. It is closed, bounded and convex, which implies that it is a Chebyshev set, as they say in approximation theory; every element of $L^2(0,1)$ admits exactly one element of best approximation in $A$. Now, the theory of infinite-dimensional manifolds arises precisely to try and study the best approximation problem with respect to non-convex sets, as far as I understand from skimming the book "Nonlinear approximation theory" of Braess. Searching for a manifold structure in this case seems, therefore, rather pointless.

Comment: Thanks much for following up, Guiseppe.  This is only a small part of a problem I am trying to work on.  What I am really interested in is finding (which may be extremely difficult and, likely, only partly successful) the orbits of a certain family of vector fields acting on $A$.  (Think of $A$ as the state space of a control system, and the family of vector fields as the control space.)  So, ideally, it would be to find the sets of $A$ reachable from a given, initial, state in $A$, by these controls.  And even $A$ is a simplification of the true set of interest (which arises

Comment: from yet another problem, fundamental to computation theory).

Comment: And sorry I misspelled your name--MSE is not allowing me to edit that comment any more.

Comment: In my opinion is it better to ask another question, more focused on the problem.

Comment: I agree.  I just didn't want to put the labor of my research on crowdsourcing, without being able to give credit appropriately.